# How to test a panic in Golang?

Tags: json, unit-testing, go, goconvey

```
func good(json) string {

  \\do something
 err = json.Unmarshal(body, &list)
 if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to parse json %s",err))
 }

}

func Testgood_PanicStatement(t *testing.T) {
  Convey("And Invalid Json return error",t, func() {
    actual := good("garbage json")
    So(func() {},shoulPanic)
    So(actual ,ShouldEqual,"")
  }
}
```

Outcome

Line 34: - Unable to parse json ,{%!e(string=invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string) %!e(int64=50)}

goroutine 8 [running]:

**Question**:It seems like when I am passing garbage json file.It is panicking and doesn't execute any of the So statements?How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use recover().

```
func Testgood_PanicStatement(t *testing.T) {
  Convey("And Invalid Json return error",t, func() {
    defer func() {
      if r := recover(); r != nil {
        So(func() {},shouldPanic)
        So(actual ,ShouldEqual,"")
      }
    }()
    actual := good("garbage json")
  }
}
```

Lear more about:

1. [Golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

Answer (score 3):

Upvoting the answer of [sadlil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476121/sadlil) as correct I want to point out, that panicking functions are not good practice. Rather convert the panic into an error INSIDE the function and test the error instead.

```
func good(json) (s string, err error) {
  defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
      err = fmt.Errorf("Error in good: %v", r)
    }
  }()

  \\do something
  err = json.Unmarshal(body, &list)
  if err != nil {
    # leaving the panic statement for demonstration. In this case
    # you could just: return "", err
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to parse json %s",err))
  }

  return
}
```